# Генератор математических примеров с проверкой на js

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, события, условия

У меня следующая задача. Сделать Тренажёр устного счёта. Идея почти реализована.

Вот подробное описание того, *как по задумке должно работать*: ввожу данные в поля для ввода (Минимальное число, максимальное число, количество примеров. Между полями для максимального и минимального чисел знак производимой операции) и нажимаю на кнопку **"Generate"**. После этого генерируется *один* пример с рандомными числами, сгенерированными в данном диапазоне. Возле примера input для ввода ответа. Внизу появляется кнопка **"Checkout"** для проверки. После нажатия на кнопку **"Checkout"**, если пример решён верно, снизу от input появляется надпись "Верно", цикл генерирует следующий пример и **генерировать он их будет после каждого правильного ответа будет до тех пор, пока их число не будет равняться тому, что пользователь ранее ввёл в третий input**. Если неправильно то должна появиться надпись "Неверно" и ничего кроме этого.

Мой код работает не так.

```js
let minimum = document.querySelector('#minimum');
let maximum = document.querySelector('#maximum');
let select = document.querySelector('#select');
let taskAmount = document.querySelector('#amount');
let button = document.querySelector('.button');
let taskWrapper = document.querySelector('.tasks');
let submitBtnWrapper = document.querySelector('.submit');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let minimumN = Number(minimum.value);
    let maximumN = Number(maximum.value);
    let taskAmountN = Number(taskAmount.value);
    let sign = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    let massive = new Array(taskAmountN);
    for (let i = 0; i < massive; i++) {
        function random(min, max) {
            localStorage.num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min) + min);
            localStorage.num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min) + min);
            taskWrapper.innerHTML += `
                <div class="tasks__wrapper">
                    <label class="tasks__item">${localStorage.num1} ${sign} ${localStorage.num2} = </label>
                    <input type="number" class="tasks__input" placeholder="Answer">
                    <div class="checking"></div>
                </div>
                `;
        }
        submitBtnWrapper.innerHTML = '<button class="submit__button">checkout</button>';
        if (i >= 1) {
            let submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit__button');
            submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                let allTasksWrappers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.tasks__wrapper')];
                for (let j = 0; j < allTasksWrappers.length; j++) {
                    let lastElement = allTasksWrappers[allTasksWrappers.length - 1];
                    let answerValue = lastElement.querySelector('.tasks__input');
                    let answerFromInput = Number(answerValue.value);
                    let tasksWrapper = document.querySelector('.checking');
                    if (sign == '+') {
                        let realAnswer = Number(localStorage.num1) + Number(localStorage.num2);
                        if (realAnswer == answerFromInput) {
                            tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Верно</p>';
                            random(minimumN, maximumN);
                        } else {
                            tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Неверно</p>';
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else if (sign == '-') {
                        let realAnswer = Number(localStorage.num1) - Number(localStorage.num2);
                        if (realAnswer == answerFromInput) {
                            tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Верно</p>';
                            random(minimumN, maximumN);
                        } else {
                            tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Неверно</p>';
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else if (sign == '*') {
                        let realAnswer = Number(localStorage.num1) * Number(localStorage.num2);
                        if (realAnswer == answerFromInput) {
                            tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Верно</p>';
                            random(minimumN, maximumN);
                        } else {
                            tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Неверно</p>';
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else if (sign == '/') {
                        let realAnswer = Number(localStorage.num1) / Number(localStorage.num2);
                        if (realAnswer == answerFromInput) {
                            tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Верно</p>';
                            random(minimumN, maximumN);
                        } else {
                            tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Неверно</p>';
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        } else if (i == 0) {
            random(minimumN, maximumN);
            let submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit__button');
            submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                let answerValue = document.querySelector('.tasks__input');
                let answerFromInput = answerValue.value;
                let tasksWrapper = document.querySelector('.checking');
                if (sign == '+') {
                    let realAnswer = Number(localStorage.num1) + Number(localStorage.num2);
                    if (realAnswer == answerFromInput) {
                        tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Верно</p>';
                        random(minimumN, maximumN);
                    } else {
                        tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Неверно</p>';
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (sign == '-') {
                    let realAnswer = Number(localStorage.num1) - Number(localStorage.num2);
                    if (realAnswer == answerFromInput) {
                        tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Верно</p>';
                        random(minimumN, maximumN);
                    } else {
                        tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Неверно</p>';
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (sign == '*') {
                    let realAnswer = Number(localStorage.num1) * Number(localStorage.num2);
                    if (realAnswer == answerFromInput) {
                        tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Верно</p>';
                        random(minimumN, maximumN);
                    } else {
                        tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Неверно</p>';
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (sign == '/') {
                    let realAnswer = Number(localStorage.num1) / Number(localStorage.num2);
                    if (realAnswer == answerFromInput) {
                        tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Верно</p>';
                        random(minimumN, maximumN);
                    } else {
                        tasksWrapper.innerHTML = '<p>Неверно</p>';
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
:root {
    --default-black: #111111;
    --medium-black: #202020;
    --light-black: #969696;
    --white: #f3f3f3;
    --blue: #006bc9;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: var(--medium-black);
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: var(--medium-black);
    color: var(--light-black);
    font-size: 16px;
}
.container {
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
}
section {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.inputs__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
input {
    padding: 10px 14px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid var(--light-black);
    outline: none;
    color: var(--white);
    margin: 10px;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
input::placeholder {
    color: var(--light-black);
}
input:focus {
    border: 1px solid var(--blue);
}
select {
    border: 1px solid var(--light-black);
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}
select option {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--default-black);
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.button-wrapper, .submit {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
button {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid var(--light-black);
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
    border: 1px solid var(--blue);
    color: var(--blue);
}
.tasks {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.submit {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Counting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="inputs__wrapper">
            <input type="number" name="minimum" id="minimum" placeholder="Minimal">
            <select name="select" id="select">
                <option value="">+</option>
                <option value="">-</option>
                <option value="">/</option>
                <option value="">*</option>
            </select>
            <input type="number" name="maximum" id="maximum" placeholder="Maximum">
            <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="Amount of tasks">
        </section>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
            <button class="button">generate</button>
        </div>
        <section class="tasks"></section>
        <section class="submit"></section>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мой код работает не так.

Предложу вот такой подход для реализации твоей задумки...

Там пока нет проверок на корректность ввода. С делением я не стал связываться... Исключительно "как идея" которую потом можно будет развивать далее.

```js
const act = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
}
const oa = document.querySelector('section select')
const ob = document.querySelector('section button')
const oi = document.querySelectorAll('section input')
const oc = document.querySelector('content')
Object.keys(act).forEach(v => {
  const o = document.createElement('option')
  o.value = v
  o.textContent = v
  oa.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', o)
})
ob.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const n = +oi[2].value  
  let i = 0
  let ok = 0
  task()
  //
  function task() {
    const v = oi[1].value - oi[0].value
    const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * v) + +oi[0].value
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * v) + +oi[0].value
    const o = data.content.children[0].cloneNode(true)
    const os = o.querySelectorAll('span')
    os[0].textContent = ++i
    os[1].textContent = a
    os[2].textContent = oa.value
    os[3].textContent = b
    o.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
      const v = +o.querySelector('input').value
      const or = o.querySelector('.res')
      if (v == act[oa.value](a, b)) {
        or.textContent = 'Правильно'
        ++ok
      } else {
        or.textContent = 'Ошибка'
      }
      if (ok < n) task()
    })
    oc.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', o)
  }
})
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <input placeholder='Минимальный' />
    <select></select>
    <input placeholder='Максимальный' />
    <input placeholder='Количество испытаний' />
  </div>
  <button>Старт</button>  
</section>
<content></content>
<template id='data'>
  <article>
    <p>
      Задание №<span></span> 
    </p>
    <div>
      <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> = <input />
    </div>
    <button>Проверить</button>
    <p class='res'></p>
  </article>
</template>
```